# Delphi TBitMap transparency from ImageList to a button

Tags: delphi, bitmap, pascal, alpha-transparency

I am trying to create a custom icon button with a transparent bitmap image, below the code.
The icon is stored in an ImageList connected to an ActionList.

```
bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
BmpObj := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  ImageList.GetBitmap(ActionList.Actions[i].ImageIndex, bitmap);

  bitmap.Transparent := TRUE;
  bitmap.TransparentColor := clWhite;
  bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;

  bitmap.SaveToStream(BmpObj);
finally
  BmpObj.Free;
  bitmap.Free;
end;
```

I don't know what I am missing.. Anyone has an idea about this problem?

Comment: What is `FDMPanello`? Is it relevant to your question? What is `TwhIconButton`? Is it relevant to your question? What is `TextureInit()`? What is `LIcon`? Please rewrite your question without these unknown components and simplify as much as you can to still show the behaviour you are asking about. IOW please provide a [mre].

Comment: Is the background of the image perfectly white?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified ImageList uses color of the Bottom-Left pixel as transparent color. That transparency is then transferred to any control that draws an image from the said ImageList. So in most cases you don't have to set transparency color by yourself.

Comment: @XylemFlow Yes, it is

Comment: @TomBrunberg Tom, it is a little difficult for me to reproduce an example without using these specific components.. i think it's more related to the bitmap usage

Comment: @Lomoo I see you are setting the `TransparentColor ` property of your bitmap before you are saving it to stream. `Transparent` and `TransparentColor ` properties are only used when drawing the said bitmap. They have no effect when saving the said bitmap. So you can't use them to essentially remove white pixels from the image which I'm guessing you are trying to do. The white pixels will be omitted ruing drawing of your image.

Comment: @SilverWarior so should i set both properties after saving it to stream?

Comment: Even if it would be difficult to recreate the problem with some other components/controls, you are certainly able to answer my questions what types they are!

Comment: Don't we just need an alpha channel

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how?

Comment: @TomBrunberg FDMPannello is a DataModule that contains specific code to create the controls in runtime with an action list. TwhIconButton is a custom control as TextureInit that is a method of my TTexture class. I am not the creator of these components, maybe the problem is inside these controls?

Comment: I don't know how you make your images, but for many years now the clean way to handle transparency is with an alpha channel. I'm sure that you can read up on this online.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if i open the image in an editor my image is actually transparent, so it has a correct alpha channel

Comment: Then why are you setting transparent and transparent colour on the bitmap object?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i was doing some attempts..

Comment: @Lomoo Your picture might have an Alpha transparency but by default VCL TBitmap does not support Alpha channel since it works in RGB and not RGBA color mode.

Answer (score 1):

Without better knowledge about the components I asked about, I show the basic way of having transparent image on many Windows controls.

Take a `TImageList` and fill it with the images you want to use. The lower left pixel determines the transparent color. In my example black numbers are placed on white background.

On the button, set property `Images` to your `ImageList` and `ImageIndex` to a valid image number (0 .. ). The image will appear on the button, with the white colored areas transparent.

In the image below, I include a `TImage` with the bitmap so you can see the actual colors.

Note no code required.

[image]

Comment: @Lomoo Did my answer above answer your question?